# Python Selenium: wait until class is visible

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automated-tests

I'm trying to get data from a website with different webpages.

My code looks like this:

```
item_List = []
def scrape(pageNumber):
    driver.get(url + pageExtension + str(pageNumber))
    items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Item-information")
    for item in items:
        item_List.append(item.text)
    return item_List
```

Right now I'm able to collect the data that I want from one page.
When I run:

```
 print scrape(23)
```

I get the results I need. But when I run:

```
print scrape(14) #any page number really
print scrape(23)
```

Selenium first loads the page "url + pageExtension + str(14)" and successfully gets the data. It then loads "url + pageExtension + str(23)" but doesn't scrape the data. I get the following error code:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:    
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I assume this is caused by the browser not loading the second page fast enough resulting in selenium not being able to scrape the class I'm looking for. I've tried some waiting functions, but thus far I haven't been successful. Help would really be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK `StaleElementReferenceException` raises if you got a webelement or list of elements, like `items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Item-information")` and then after page update you're trying to handle `items`. You should re-define element (list) on each iteration that could cause page update

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. How would you do so?

Comment: ok... Can you check the first line of exception log to find out which element is actually stale?

Comment: Also you might need to change your question title as it is quite senseless and does not corresponds to described issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
item_List = []
def scrape(pageNumber):
    driver.get(url + pageExtension + str(pageNumber))
    items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Item-information")
    for item in items:
        item_List.append(item.text)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
          EC.staleness_of((By.CLASS_NAME, "Item-information"))) # waits till the element is NOT attached to the DOM.
    return item_List
```

---

**Note:** As you are looking for the same elements (with same class name), `items` still contains the references to the elements of previous that you already visited. (here `Page 14`). so, when you visit `Page 24`, `items` refers to the elements which are in `Page 14` but not in `Page 24`, so gives `StaleElementReferenceException`.

Comment: Thanks Naveen! This might be really simple, but how can I use page number in visibility_of_element_located?

Comment: does the title contains page number? or page number is displayed as part of the web page?  If page number is part of the HTML, then only you can use it. anyways, that is just hint. you can go for any element.

Comment: What if I can't find a unique element? Every page is exactly the same apart from the information I'm trying to scrape.

Comment: Have you tried with the code that I shared as an answer? still facing the issue? If yes, add sleep of 1-2 seconds.

Comment: one more option is to wait for the body tag. try that as well, i.e., (By.TAG, "body")

Comment: I don't get an error, but the output I receive is the same for both pages. (I get the output for the first page twice)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130221/discussion-between-titusadam-and-naveen).